# Transfer data from clickhouse to PostgreSQL running on different machines

Tags: postgresql, pipe, clickhouse

My clickhouse db runs on `some_ip:8122`

clickhouse db:

```
create table  chtable
(
  val_1             UInt32,
  val_2             UInt32,
  val_date_full     DateTime,
  val_id            UInt64,
  val_date_short    Date
)
engine = MergeTree(val_date_short, val_id , 8192);
```

My postgresql db runs on `another_ip:5437`

postgresql db:

```
create table psqltable
(
      val_1             integer,
      val_2             integer,
      val_date_full     timestamp,
      val_id            integer,
      val_date_short    date
      val_id            integer not null,
      val_date_short    date    not null,
      constraint psqltable_pkey
      primary key (val_date_short, val_id)
);
```

How do I copy data from the clickhouse db to the postgresql db (running on different machines) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clickhouse doesn't support writing to ODBC tables yet. (mysql has this functionality). Suppose you have both clickhouse-client and psql on some machine that can reach both `<some-ip>` and `<another_ip>`. You can achieve this by

```
clickhouse-client --host <some-ip> --port 8122 --query 'select * from chtable;' | psql -h <another_ip> -p 5437 -c 'copy psqltable from stdin'
```